# Rails 3 - Devise/ActionMailer/RUBY-SMTP  causing a segmentation fault

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, smtp, actionmailer

OK - I'm in way over my head here.  I'm using:

```
  - ruby-1.9.3-p0
  - rails-3.1.3
  - mail-2.3.0
  - devise-1.5.3
```

Trying to turn on Devise's `:confirmable` option and start up smtp services in my app.  As soon as I add `/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb`, add Devise's necessary columns in my DB, and the `:confirmable` attribute to my `User` model, I get a segmentation fault.  It occurs right after a user signs up. `Devise` is trying to send out the confirmation email, causing the ruby smtp library to crash with the following:

```
... lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:583: [BUG] Segmentation fault
```

The last entry in `log/development.log`:

```
Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.2ms)
```

My `/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb` file:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "mydomain.com",
  :user_name            => "support@mydomain.com",
  :password             => "???????",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

My `config/environments/development.rb` file has the following:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Here is the germane code from ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb (line 583 is near the middle):

```
def ssl_socket(socket, context)
  OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new socket, context
end

def tlsconnect(s)
  verified = false
  s = ssl_socket(s, @ssl_context)
  logging "TLS connection started"
  s.sync_close = true
  s.connect  # THIS IS LINE 583
  if @ssl_context.verify_mode != OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    s.post_connection_check(@address)
  end
  verified = true
  s
ensure
  s.close unless verified
end
```

It looks like the segmentation fault occurs when smtp is trying to connect via a SSL socket connection ( `s.connect` ).  In `setup_mail.rb` I've tried setting `:enable_starttls_auto` to both `true` and `false`.  I don't get the segmentation fault when it is set to `false` but no email goes out, so that is useless.

I'm easily able to connect to gmail's smtp service by running this command from my Mac:

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

Not sure where to go from here - any suggestions?

Comment: operating system ? if windows ... :X

Comment: In another forum I got this suggestion:

paul_at_nines.org> Jan 29 12:40PM -0500  ... are you having this problem?
http://www.christopherirish.com/2011/09/02/ruby-1-9-2-segmentation-fault-and-openssl/

This looked promising.  I tried it but then RVM started screwing up my Rails install.  It was so FUBAR that I had to completely stop using RVM and switch to Homebrew to install ruby just so I could get Rails running again.  It was unbelievable!  If the seg fault issue goes away with the Homebrew ruby I'll post an update here.

Comment: Also, I found a page in the RMV docs that deals with OpenSSL - someone might find it of value:  http://beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/

Comment: I was able to test the Homebrew-installed ruby and still ended up with a segmentation fault.  :-(   So I guess I'm back to seeing if I can get RVM to play nice with Rails...

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar error (in net/http).

Doing this fixed it:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm pkg install iconv
rvm pkg install readline
rvm reinstall 1.9.3  --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_path/usr  --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr  --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the way Rails interacts with OpenSSL. This post sums it up very well. http://www.22ideastreet.com/debug/smtp-rb14-bug-segmentation-fault/

The fix is to add this to your .bashrc/.zshrc/.bash_profile

```
export RUBYOPT="-ropenssl"
```