# Segmentation fault using ActionMailer with Ruby 1.9.3-p125

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, openssl, actionmailer

I was happily sending email from my web app using ActionMailer, using ruby 1.9.2-p180. Then I upgraded to ruby 1.9.3-p125, using RVM.

Now I am getting a segmentation fault every time I try to send and email.

```
/Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:583: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0092 p:---- s:0499 b:0499 l:000498 d:000498 CFUNC  :connect
c:0091 p:0059 s:0496 b:0496 l:000495 d:000495 METHOD /Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:583
c:0090 p:0255 s:0491 b:0490 l:001180 d:001180 METHOD /Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:560
c:0089 p:0047 s:0482 b:0482 l:000481 d:000481 METHOD /Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:519
c:0088 p:0496 s:0475 b:0475 l:000474 d:000474 METHOD /Users/disaacs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:128
c:0087 p:0031 s:0464 b:0464 l:000463 d:000463 METHOD /Users/disaacs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/message.rb:1989
c:0086 p:0009 s:0460 b:0460 l:000436 d:000459 BLOCK  /Users/disaacs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/message.rb:230
c:0085 p:0021 s:0458 b:0458 l:000440 d:000457 BLOCK  /Users/disaacs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionmailer-3.1.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:432
```

I've seen some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030088/rails-3-devise-actionmailer-ruby-smtp-causing-a-segmentation-fault), but nothing with definitive answers. Is this a well know issue with no answer?

I am running Rails 3.1.1 on OSX 10.6.8.

Comment: Are you using an gems that contain C extensions?

Comment: No, I don't think so. My Gemfile lists devise, hirb, cancan, kaminari, sqlite3.

Comment: The other similar thread seems to point a finger at openssl, but no explicit blame is assigned, and no solution is proposed.

Comment: sqlite3 is a wrapper for the SQLite C library. There could also be things that Rails itself depends on. Rebuilding the offending gems might help (or it might be waste of time).

Comment: What's the easiest way to rebuild the offending gem? And, for that matter, which is the offending gem? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with Paperclip that was related to how openssl was compiled when installing ruby 1.9.3.  Not 100% sure this is the same issue your having, but I'd bet it is.

To solve this issue I reinstalled ruby and fresh gemset after installing the rvm openssl pkg:

```
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ rvm remove 1.9.3-p125
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p125 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Comment: I don't know how you figured that out, but it worked like a charm. Thanks bunches!