# Unable to fix rails smtp.rb error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, smtp

I followed the post here,

[Rails 3 - Devise/ActionMailer/RUBY-SMTP  causing a segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030088/rails-3-devise-actionmailer-ruby-smtp-causing-a-segmentation-fault/16256541#16256541)

But, trying to add this variable to my home directory's .bashrc or .zshrc or .bash_profile does not seem to provide this variable. After adding RUBYOPT to these files, I tried to echo $RUBYOPT, but nothing comes on the screen.

Do I need to restart my laptop or add this variable somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

do the following:

```
$ echo 'export RUBYOPT="-ropenssl"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

and then see if you have `RUBYOPT` is set or not

Comment: Thanks. That does it, but only for that terminal window. If I open another window, then RUBYOPT is not set there.